# When I use Java 8 Liquibase ignores classes that override liquibase classes

Tags: java-8, liquibase

I am using liquibase 3.3.2. My class extends DB2Database and it overrides isReservedWord method. When I use Java 7 it works fine and it always uses my own  isReservedWord class. But when I use Java 8, liquibase ignores my extended class and uses isReservedWord in AbstractJdbcDatabase. Could you please let me know why it behaves likes this with Java 8?

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: This is probably a bug and should be reported to Liquibase. https://liquibase.jira.com/projects/CORE/

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I reported on Liquibase jira: https://liquibase.jira.com/projects/CORE/issues/CORE-2798?filter=addedrecently